# MS bot framework use the user name and his properties throughout the session in various functions

Tags: c#, botframework, session-variables, direct-line-botframework

Hi I'm using MS Bot framework, v4 and i'm using C# code. I've deployed the bot in Direct-line bot channel.

I'm getting the user name and his properties in the front end using JavaScript and passing it to the bot. 
Using the state management, i can get the manage the user's name in the onmemberaddedasync activity.

```
 protected override async Task OnMembersAddedAsync(IList<ChannelAccount> membersAdded, ITurnContext<IConversationUpdateActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

    {
        var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
        var userProfile = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile());

        foreach (var member in membersAdded)
        {
           if (member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
         {
                userProfile.Name = member.Name.Replace('.', ' ');


                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text($"Hi  **{member.Name.Replace('.',' ')}**. I'm bot, "), cancellationToken);

            }
        }

    }
```

Everything is working fine till here, when i tried to use the user name in OnMessageActivityAsync, the scope of member is not extend, hence i created a global variable assigned the user name in it, which is now extended and can be used in other methods, but its not with respected to the current user's session, if some other users is logged in the bot, it takes their name.

And also, i've some custom user properties similar to email id, but this will change during the conversation, and i need to capture that value and pass it to the front end JavaScript code to do some front end activities, and this is also not session specific.

is there any options to maintain session for username used in multiple functions and other user's properties.

please suggest a way.

Comment: [Save user and conversation data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)?

Comment: @stuartd thanks for replying,  I developed the bot using the statemanagement template and the same you had mentioned, the challenge what I'm facing is accessing the conversation state and user state data in other methods like OnTurnAsync & OnEventActivityAsync, is there any possible ways for that.

Comment: consider my case: i will assign the user name as userProfile.Name = member.Name  in OnMembersAddedAsync method and i want to use the same in OnMessageActivityAsync method ? how to do that

Comment: There's an example of accessing user and conversation state in `OnMessageActivityAsync` in that article? Does that not work for you?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/45.state-management

Comment: @JeganBaskaran Did you found a solution for this ?

Comment: @AshishKumar, I've updated the answer below, try that and if that worked for you please upvote, if not let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for using the username through out the session, we can capture the user's name from the turncontext itself, as mentioned below.

```
 await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Hi, **" + turnContext.Activity.From.Name + "** How are you !"), cancellationToken);
```

turnContext.Activity.From.Name => this will gives the user's name